# Can I randomly determine the outcome of an event with 5 outcomes with a d6?

Tags: dice

Could I use a d6 to find which event would happen given there were 5 events, lets say named A, B, C, D, and E? I am thinking that for 1–5, you could have the events assigned to their respective numbers, so:

1 → A
2 → B
3 → C
4 → D
5 → E
6 → Reroll the d6

Would this work? I don't have much experience in tabletop games, but it makes sense that each event A–E would have an equal chance assuming the d6 was fair.

Answer (score 64):

You have it -- roll the D6, if you roll a 6, roll again.  You'll get a flat probability curve.  Alternatively, you could roll a D10 or D20, and integer divide the result by 2 or 4 respectively (that is, 1 or 2 on the D10 become 1, 3 or 4 become 2, etc.) -- whatever is comfortable for you.

Answer (score 58):

Yes, this works: in statistics, it's known as [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

The very slight problem is that you could roll a large number of consecutive sixes so you can't *guarantee* that the procedure will finish within any particular amount of time. However, the average number of dice rolls needed is just 1.2 and there's less than a 0.5% chance of needing more than three rolls.

Comment: To be fair, you were already going to have to re-roll that die if it landed cocked or in someone's drink. Re-rolling sixes isn't that much different.

Comment: Ah, the [craps theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps_principle).  Either that or the OP's 'by symmetry' will do it.  (Both ways are predicated on not rolling sixes indefinitely, but that has probability 1.)

Comment: @GMJoe Exactly. And this procedure requires very few rerolls -- just 0.2 on average.

Comment: If you keep rolling 6's .. remember which die it is and use it next time you cast fireball ... don't roll 10 dice, just roll that die 10 times .. :) (you'll be the most popular person there ... rolling a single die ... 10 times .. O.o )

Answer (score 14):

**Yes**

The 6th "reroll" option doesn't impact the weights of each of the other events, so by giving a specific face a reroll, it's like reducing the number of faces of the die.

In the scenario you set up, each event would have a 20% chance of occuring—or in mathiness: **P(1/5)**.

Comment: _mathiness_ :o)

Answer (score 10):

This would work. Some alternatives would be to use a d10 or d20 as they are evenly divisible by 5. You could then either use the result divided by 2 for a d10 or 4 for a d20, or the result modulus 5.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have any situation in mind, just wondered in case something like this ever happened.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in the mathematical formula (who isn't??), you can see how each outcome has a 1/5 chance of happening using your method, which is what you want.

The chance of rolling a 1 under this circumstance is 1/6 (rolling a 1 first time) + 1/6 ✕ 1/6 (chance of rolling a 6 followed by a 1) + 1/6 ✕ 1/6 ✕ 1/6 (chance of rolling 2 sixes then a 1) + ...

This can be rephrased as (1/6 + 1/36 + 1/216 + ...)

Which, from the [sum of a geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), is equal to

\$ \dfrac{1 \div (1- \frac{1}{6})}{6} = \dfrac{1 \div (5/6)}{6} = \dfrac{6/5}{6} =  \dfrac{1}{5}. \$

And the same for rolling a 2,3,4,5.

Comment: Don't you mean (1/6 + 1/36 + 1/216+...)? I do like thinking about the math behind things, this is part of why I originally asked.

Comment: IMO it's simpler to get the probability it this way: \$P(X=n) = 1/6 + P(X=n)*(1/6)\$ (to get result *n* you can roll either get it on the first dice roll or roll a 6 and repeat the process). That equation is easy to solve and you also get \$P(X=n) = 1/5\$.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you can't guarantee that it would happen after N throws of the die for any finite value of N.  If you agree to re-roll (and discount the roll) when the die falls on 6, the probability of never getting anything but 6 is 0.  But you may get a 6 an arbitrarily large number of consecutive times.  However, if you ignore all the 6's, then each roll that remains has a 1 in 5 probability of occurring.